# SharePoint Default SignOut Page Go Back To Site Link Show the Current User is Still Signed In

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication

On my site collecton, when a user clicks Sign Out and redirected to Signout.aspx page, the user will see a Go Back to Site link (in some browsers, it will also prompt you to close the tab to completely sign out).

When user clicks on the Go Back to Site, he/she will be redirected to the site's home page. Strangely, on Chrome, some users still see that they were logged in (just like clicking the browser's back button effect), but when they refresh the page, they have been signed out. On the other browser (even IE), this behavior randomly happens. Have tried to clear cookies, but no luck.

Is there anyway to make sure user has been signed out when they click Go Back to Site link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often a user with a company computer signs in to a domain when she signs in to the computer. This means that she is already authenticated and have access to the SharePoint site where she has access.

By selecting "sign out" you get to the signout.aspx, but she is still authenticated in the domain. The only way to force sign in and sign out in this case is to add the site in question in Internet Explorer > Internet Option > Security > Restricted Sites. However, this is not a recommended approach since it will force users to sign in to the site every time she opens the browser again.

Comment: So that behavior is by design? Because I think it is quite useless when a user clicked on Go Back to Site, and still sees that he/she is logged in (even the navigation menu still shows links that available to logged in users only), and when he/she tries to access a custom page / web part / whatever that requires user to be signed in, they get an error message / unauthorized message.

Comment: @AWJ Yes. And be aware that authentication IS NOT under the control of SharePoint. It's Active Directory that authenticates a user.

Answer (score 2):

Open Internet Options from IE and go to Security > Custom Level> User Authentication > Prompt for user name and password.

[image]

post your result after applying it.